# What sort of fuzzy flood fill algorithms are there?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, flood-fill

I'm implementing a flood fill algorithm for the project I'm currently working on.  I'm using it for the normal purpose, image editing.  I have no problem with the basic algorithm, but I'd like a better looking fill.

In many cases areas of my image will have regions that are mostly one color, but which are bordered by pixels which are slightly lighter or darker.  I'd like to know an algorithm for a "fuzzy" flood fill that won't leave these border pixels.  I've tried to fill all pixels withn two different, simple, distance metrics of the origin pixel:

1. a Manhattan Distance on all 3 color components: red, green, and blue
2. the maximum of the distance between the color components.

Neither of these do the trick, often leaving borders and occasionally filling adjacent regions of a visually distinct but "close" color.

I don't think there is a magic bullet to solve my problem, but I'd be interested in knowing any algorithms which I might try to get a better result, or even where I might usefully look to find such algorithms.  Looking around the net I've found reference to something called the "fuzzy flood fill mean shift algorihm", but I'm not sure that's even the same thing.

Comment: Are you trying to do an alpha'd border, so that pixels which are similar don't get changed to the fill colour but to a weighted average between their existing colour, the region's previous colour, and the fill colour?

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to do some anti-aliasing along the borders. I suspect that RGB isn't the proper space to work in, as it can result in some pretty strange effects. You might look into using HSV instead.

Comment: Peter Taylor - That particular strategy hadn't occurred to me, but I may want to try it.  Thank you.
Jim Mischel - I could translate it to HSV, but I'm not sure what I would do after that.  Hopefully that would reduce the filling of adjacent regions, but even with various distance metrics I'm not sure that would help remove the heavily alpha-d borders I have (where I move in 3 pixels or so from RGB 0xFFFFFF to 0x808080 to 0x000000, leaving an ugly gray border after the fill).  I wouldn't be able to just ignore that large a value difference.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Using the actual distance seems natural:  D = Sqrt(R^2 + G^2 + B^2)

Then define a tolerance parameter that specifies the maximum distance from the original pixel (in colorspace) that the test pixel can be.  If it is greater than that value, do not flood outward from that pixel.

Tweak the tolerance from 0 to Sqrt(255^2 + 255^2 + 255^2) until you see the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using the qualities of the local pixels rather than the origin pixels.  You could do an effect much like an anisotropic diffusion filter.  Enqueue a neighbor if the gradient between the current pixel (in the fill) and the neighbor pixel is low enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should set tolerance not with a single number but rather with a range. Say, from 20% to 50% would mean that when color difference is 20% you change the color of this pixel completely. When it's greater then 50% you don't fill this pixel. And when the difference lays in a range from 20% to 50% you blend the old color with the new color with ratio of (d-t_min)/(t_max-t_min) where d is color difference and t_max and t_min is your tolerance range (expressed in 0...1).
I never seen such an algorithm ever implemented; maybe I just invented it.